# How to enable VT-x in HP550 laptop?

Tags: bios, virtualization

I am using HP550 Notebook PC, I can't find option to enable VT-x in my laptop. In my BIOS settings, I don't have options related Virtualization Technology, my BIOS version is F0.0.

I also tried to update my BIOS with version F1.0, but it results in 'unhandled exception' while installing. I don't know how to fix it.

Please give me solution for this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

That model of laptop came with 4 options for processors:

- Intel Core 2 Duo Processor T5470
- Intel Core 2 Duo Processor T5270
- Intel Celeron Dual Core Processor
- Intel Celeron M Processor 530.

None of these processors offers VT-x capability. A BIOS update will not resolve your problem. You will have to get a new PC if you wish to use VT-x technology.